# Elementary OS 5.1 Appcenter Few Application

Tags: appcenter, release-hera

I am using Elementary OS 5.0 for a while. Today I just installed 5.1. In the appcenter the amount of the app is less than it should be. To give an example most common apps like Libreoffice, Octave, Spyder cannot be found in the appcenter. During whole day, I couldn't find any way to solve this. I am asking your help. Have a good day. Thank u for your interest. Here, the screenshot from the appcenter.

[image: appcenter]

Comment: are you online?

Comment: I  faced breezing a couple of time while shut down pc and low wifi signal problem at last night .I think it is better to qo with manjaro xfce for me up to January- term break of college. Thank you all for your help and effort. Have a good day

Answer (score 1):

I just updated my home computer in Elementary OS 5.1 HERA

Looking for each of your application, on my laptop still under EOS 5.0 and my home computer under EOS 5.1

I find exactly the same result on the appcenter to know

- **libreOffice** OK in 5.0 and 5.1
  [image: app-center LibreOffice]
- **GNU Octave** OK in 5.0 and 5.1
  [image: app-center-octave]
- **Spyder** OK in 5.0 and 5.1
  [image]

checked the contents of your source list of the app center, now here is mine in my Elementary OS 5.1 HERA

```
$ cat /etc/apt/sources.list.d/appcenter.list
deb http://packages.elementary.io/appcenter bionic main
$ cat /etc/apt/sources.list.d/elementary.list
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/elementary-os/stable/ubuntu bionic main
deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/elementary-os/stable/ubuntu bionic main
$ cat /etc/apt/sources.list.d/patches.list
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/elementary-os/os-patches/ubuntu bionic main
deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/elementary-os/os-patches/ubuntu bionic main
```

NOTE : every screenshot comes from my Elementary OS 5.1 HERA

good day

Comment: Thank you for your effort. I made a fresh install one more time. Source list is the same as yours however I faced same problem again :(. To maintain my works in college I just installed Octave and Libreoffice from Flathub, Spyder and Wxmaxima from Ubuntu repositories by using terminal. Best regards

Comment: You are welcome but it is very strange... I add others source list from 5.1 ELEMENTARY.list and PATCHES.list

Comment: After 3 years, I have realized that I didn't state the reason of this problem. All it is about the language in my cases. Just select English in the process of installation instead of Turkish. I hope it will help you.