# sudo apt-get update problem

Tags: ppa, sudo

E: 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/cybre/elementaryplus/ubuntu bionic Release' deposunda Release dosyası yok.
W: Böyle bir depodan güvenli bir şekilde güncelleme yapılamaz, bu nedenle depo devre dışı bırakılmıştır.
W: Depo oluşturma ve kullanıcı yapılandırması hakkında ayrıntılı bilgi için apt-secure(8) rehber sayfasında bulunabilir

Answer (score 0):

Appcenterdan bir ekran görüntüsü yükleyebilir misiniz? Daha önceleri Elementary os'u Türkçe dili ile kurmak Appcenter'da bazı kaynaklara erişimde soruna yol açmaktaydı.

[Elementary OS 5.1 Appcenter Few Application](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/21341/elementary-os-5-1-appcenter-few-application)

Answer (score 0):

Do this following command. It will resolve the problem

sudo apt-add-repository -r ppa:cybre/elementaryplus